# $http.post not working with JSON data

Tags: http, post, angularjs

I am building an application using `AngularJS` and I have a login form from which I want to send `JSON` data as request body.

In my controller;

```
$scope.credentials = {userid: $scope.userid, password: $scope.password};
$scope.login = function () {
$http({
                method : 'POST',
                url    : 'http://localhost/login.json',
                data   : $scope.credentials,
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
            }).success(function (data) {
                // code
            }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.status = status + ' ' + headers;
            console.log($scope.status);
        });
};
```

But when I am submitting the form POST request is not performing and I am getting a message in the console like;

```
0 function (name) {
"use strict";

    if (!headersObj) headersObj =  parseHeaders(headers);

    if (name) {
      return headersObj[lowercase(name)] || null;
    }

    return headersObj;
  }
```

What am I doing wrong here?

If I changed the line

```
headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
```

to

```
headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
```

the POST request is making. But I don't want to send it as form values instead I want to send the request as JSON.

Comment: See you chrome\ firebug browser console, for requests being made and the response you receive.

Comment: No request is making instead it's showing a message like the one I pasted in my question.

Comment: if `myurl` is a string variable it should not have quotes `''`

Comment: url is not actually 'myurl'. I just used it in my question. Edited my question. Please have a look.

Comment: What are you using on the server to process the request?  It's possible that the web framework doesn't accept the 'application/json' content type for posts.  What status code is returned when you POST json?

Comment: I resolved it myself. Anyway thanks all for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You should encode javascript object to corresponding mime-type data in order to post data. If you are using jQuery, try to use `$.param($scope.credentials)` instead of just `$scope.credentials`.

Comment: It's not working. I think this step is using while we are sending the request body as form values. I need to send the request body as JSON.

Comment: Try to remove `headers:` parameter at all.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're `POST`ing to `http://localhost/login.json` which is not any script that is able to receive `POST`requests with form data.